# What's the efficient way of checking the format of file by Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file like:

```
Fruit.Store={
    #blabla
    "customer-id:12345,item:store/apple" = (1,2);   #blabla
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/banana" = (1,3);   #blabla
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/watermelon" = (1,4);
    #blabla
    "customer-id:67890,item:store/watermelon" = (1,6);
    #The following two are unique
    "customer-id:0000,item:store/" = (100, 100);
    #
    "" = (0,0)
};
```

Except the comments, each line has the same format: `customer-id` and `item:store/` are fixed, and `customer-id` is a 5-digit number. The last two records are unique. How could I make sure the file is in the right format elegantly? I am thinking about using the flag for the first special line `Fruit.Store={` and than for the following lines split each line by "," and "=", and if the splitted line is not correct, match them with the last two records. I want to use Ruby for it. Any advice? Thank you.

I am also thinking about using regular expression for the format, and wrote:

```
^"customer:\d{5},item:store\/\D*"=\(\d*,\d*\);
```

but I want to combine these two situations (with comment and without comment):

```
^"customer:\d{5},item:store\/\D*"=\(\d*,\d*\);$

^"customer:\d{5},item:store\/\D*"=\(\d*,\d*\);#.*$
```

how could I do it? Thanks

Comment: How about the value for each for `item:store/`, any limitations/rules to consider?

Comment: Instead of inventing your own format why not use something like YAML, JSON, or something like that?

Comment: "item:store/" is fixed and thanks @Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expressions could be a good option since each line has a fixed format; and you almost got it, your regex just needed a few tweaks:

```
(?:#.*|^"customer-id:\d{5},item:store\/\D*" *= *\(\d*, *\d*\); *(?:#.*)?)$
```

This is what was added to your current regex:

- Option to be a comment line (`#.*`) *or* (`|`) a regular line (everything after `|`).
- Check for possible spaces before and after `=`, after the comma (`,`) that separates the digits in parenthesis, and at the end of the line.
- Option to include another comment at the end of the line (`(?:#.*)?`).

So just compare each line against this regex to check for the right format.